# Как починить распаковку архива?(c#)

Tags: c#, zip, zipfile

Использую ionic.zip для распаковки, приложение forms, есть код, который распаковывает. Проблема в том, что всё время кидает ошибку, что файл уже существует, пробовал разные варианты. Вот код:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(_filename))
    zip.ExtractAll(_extractpath);}
```

Вот как пробовал:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(_filename)){
    zip.ExtractAll(_extractpath, zip.ExtractAll(_extractpath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)}
```

Comment: Есть ли в архиве файлы с одинаковыми именами?

Comment: @aepot есть, но они же в разных папках. Или это важно?

Comment: А вы при распаковке точно в разные папки их раскладываете? Или все-таки все в одну?

Comment: Там 2 разные папки рядом друг с другом. В каждой есть один и тот же файл. На него вроде и ругается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня вот так работает

```csharp
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(_filename))
{
    zip.ExtractAll(_extractpath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);                
}
```

Comment: Точно не знаю, поможет ли, т.к. эта ошибка не часто возникает. В любом случае спасибо!